# malloc causes segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am setting a pointer to pointers like in the code above. The problem is that malloc is throwing a segmentation fault no matter what I have tried. Here is the code:

```
wchar_t **Words ;
int lc = lineCounter() ;
**Words = malloc( lc * sizeof(int)  ) ;
if (**Words == NULL) return -1 ;
```

The lineCounter function is just a function that returns the number of lines in a file.
So what I try to do is free some memory that is needed to save the pointers to lc number of words.

Here is a visual representation of what I have in mind :

[image]

Comment: What is `Words` pointing at?

Comment: to a character array if I understood your question.

Comment: You are deferencing `Words` but `Words` has an indeterminate value.

Comment: I can not see how I fix this .

Comment: You do not understand the fundamental rules of pointers, because you're breaking them.  Please read this: http://ericlippert.com/2014/05/12/what-are-the-fundamental-rules-of-pointers/

Comment: Your drawing has one pointer to an array of pointers pointing to char arrays. How do you think should your code represent your intention when it consist of only one pointer and one `malloc`?

Comment: My code is not for the whole pattern just for the **point and *point ones.

Comment: The title of your question is misleading. *malloc* has nothing to do with it; you could say `*Words = giraffe()` and get the same fault. The actual cause of your problem is *dereferencing a pointer value stored in an uninitialized variable*.

Comment: @EricLippert I'd leave "malloc" in the title .. the goal of the post is to use malloc correctly (he even has the correct mental model of how it should work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me explain your code line by line:

```
wchar_t **Words ;
```

It is creating a pointer pointing to a pointer on wchar_t. The thing is, at creation it is pointing on a random area in the memory so it may not be yours.

```
*Words = malloc( lc * sizeof(int)  ) ;
```

This line dereferences the pointer and modify it's content. You're trying to modify a memory area that doesn't belong to you.

I think that what you want to do is:

```
wchar_t **Words ;
int lc = lineCounter() ;
Words = malloc( lc * sizeof(wchar_t *)  ) ;
if (Words == NULL) return -1 ;
```

And then malloc all the dimensions in your array.

EDIT:

You may want to do something like that to correspond to your scheme:

```
wchar_t **Words ;
int i = 0;

int lc = lineCounter() ;
Words = malloc( lc * sizeof(wchar_t *)  ) ;
if (Words == NULL) return -1 ;
while (i < lc)
{
  Words[i] = malloc(size_of_a_line * sizeof(wchar_t));
  if (words[i] == NULL) return -1;
  ++i;
}
```

Comment: is this going to do what I show in the dropbox file? Because I find it strange.

Comment: `*Words[i]` shall be `Words[i]`!

Comment: Right, alk. My bad. :)

Answer (score 3):

A pointer *refers to a storage location*.  A *variable* is an example of a *storage location*.

The `*` operator takes a pointer and gives you the storage location that the pointer refers to.

`words` is a pointer; it refers to a storage location of type `pointer to wchar_t`. Since it is not initialized, it is undefined what storage location it refers to.

Applying the `*` operator takes the pointer and produces the location it refers to; since you haven't said what location it refers to, writing to that location could do anything, including crash.

You need to make the pointer `words` refer to a location before you assign something to `*words`.